# PerlEmbed - C# doesn't work with Interpreter.Language = @"PerlScript"

Tags: c#

Regarding to the method in:
[PerlEmbed - C# - Mono - Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196620/perlembed-c-sharp-mono-linux?lq=1)

I got the following error when I tried to run the code above, at line

```
Interpreter.Language = @"**PerlScript**"
```

I can run a VBScript but unfortunately I couldn't run a PerlScript. Should I do/setup/add etc. something else?

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  HelpLink="MSSCRIPT.HLP"
  Message="***A script engine for the specified language can not be created.***"
  Source="ScriptControl"
  ErrorCode=-2146827908
  StackTrace:
       at MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass.set_Language(String pbstrLanguage)
       at fpu_Parsing.Perl_Interpreter.Perl_Output_returnString() in D:\Documents and Settings\labuser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\fpu_Parsing\fpu_Parsing\Perl_Interpreter.cs:line 77
       at fpu_Parsing.frmFpuAnalyzer..ctor() in D:\Documents and Settings\labuser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\fpu_Parsing\fpu_Parsing\frmFpuAnalyzer.cs:line 24
       at fpu_Parsing.Program.Main() in D:\Documents and Settings\labuser\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\fpu_Parsing\fpu_Parsing\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```