# C# - perlembed - compile error in linux

Tags: c#, c, linux, perl

i want to ask you a question about perlembed. the last entry about the below issue:
[PerlEmbed - C# - Mono - Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196620/perlembed-c-sharp-mono-linux?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I asked jonathanpeppers but he said he is not working on perl and c anymore. so i am asking to the group.

I tried to run perlembed.c on a linux machine but i got the following error. can you help me about it?

```
[root@BSG01 melih]# gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,perlembed.so -o perlembed.so perlembed.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccRP7CYZ.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccRP7CYZ.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as proposed in the error message. Use the compiler option `-fPIC`:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,perlembed.so -o perlembed.so -fPIC perlembed.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
```

**Edit:**

See [here for the documentation of `gcc`'s options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html).